# Flutter - using TextEditingController to detect if last characters typed info field matches specific charater

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm attempting to build a text field which triggers certain events which a user types in specific characters. For example, if a user types the '@' symbol, it will automatically trigger an event (in my case open an alert box). I've created a TextEditingController (_basicController) which adds a listener to the field and calls a function which looks for the last character typed into the field and detects matches to the symbol '@':

```
_detectLatestValue() {
  var userInput = _basicController.text;
  if(userInput.characters.last == "@"){
    print("call to action");
    _tagHandleSelect(_basicController.text);
  }
}
```

It seems to print ("call to action") when it's supposed to, however when i call the _tagHandleSelect function (which opens a generic dialogue box), it seems to get stuck in a loop ie each time i close the alert box it opens another.

Here is the full page code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: TextEditingControllerExample(),
      );
    }
  }

  class TextEditingControllerExample extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _TextEditingControllerExampleState createState() {
      return _TextEditingControllerExampleState();
    }
  }

  class _TextEditingControllerExampleState extends State<TextEditingControllerExample> {
    final _basicController = TextEditingController();
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _basicController.addListener(detectLatestValue);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _basicController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    _detectLatestValue() {
      var userInput = _basicController.text;
      if(userInput.characters.last == "@"){
        print("call to action");
        _tagHandleSelect(_basicController.text);
      }
    }
    Future<void> _tagHandleSelect(text) async {
      return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(text),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Form(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    child: TextField(
                        controller: _basicController,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          )
        ),
      );
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a listener to the controller can be a little hard to manage.

If you only want to listen to changes on a specific `TextField`, you can do something like this:

```
child: TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.endsWith("@")) {
            print("call to action");
            _tagHandleSelect(value);
        }
    },
),
```

This way you know `onChanged` will only be triggered once.

The listener to the `TextEditingController` will be triggered whenever the controller changes, which can be more than once for every text edit (for example, when the Text is focused or unfocused, it will be triggered).

I hope this can help you and you can develop your idea further!!